# creating a static IP various warning and nothing saying config is correct

Tags: networking, netplan

I have been trying to set up a static IP in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

The web offers different Netplan config so I picked the most simple code

[image: current installer]

When I input "Netplan try" I get the following warning

```
WARNING:root: Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.
```

Do you want to keep these settings?

Also, I have 2 ethernets but do not see a configuration for that

This was the original installer-config as DHCP

[image: DHCP config]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can ignore that warning about openvswitch.  OpenVSwitch is *NOT* standard on systems, and usually not the issue.  Netplan throws that warning because it tries blindly to poke the Open vSwitch service.  The "Do you want to keep these settings" is standard with the try call though, lets you test the applied settings first.  The warning is not related to that prompt

Comment: @user68186 Server installs don't roll with Network Manager or `nmcli` by default.

Comment: @ThomasWard thanks for that information.